# Run apache spark in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

I try to run apache spark master and worker inside virtual box (ubuntu), and connect to it from my app, but unfortunately I keep getting:

```
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed
```

I configured port redirection from the virtual machine to the hostmachine on `7077`, `6066` & `8080` and I can telnet from my host windows machine to `127.0.0.1 7077` and get connected.

I run spark master and spark worker with the following commands:

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=127.0.0.1

bash sbin/spark-daemon.sh start org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master 1 --ip 127.0.0.1 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
bash bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://127.0.0.1:7077 -c 2 -m 2000m -h 127.0.0.1
```

In the web UI I see `Spark Master at spark://127.0.0.1:7077`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For connecting to Spark Master you need to define Bridge connection on VM. Now your connection NAT  that's why you cannot connect. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged

In Bridge mode everything work fine)